# Javascript Variable : A function is called to sort the array inside the variable, how can i make the array of the variable change to it original sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Good day mates!
I just want to ask how can i retrieve the original content of an array in a variable if its being change several times already by calling a function?

heres the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var cars = ['Honda', 'Mazda', 'Toyota', 'Ambulance']; // store cars in my cars variable

        document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = cars; // display the cars in my html

        function sortCars() {
            cars.sort(); // sort the cars
            document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = cars; display sorted cars
            $('#btn').css('opacity', '0');
            $('#unsort').css(
                'opacity', '1'
                );
        }

        function unsortCars() {
            document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = cars; //what i expect to happen here is that the content of the cars which is first declare is the same. but it seems the cars variable original value is sorted already
            $('#btn').css('opacity', '1');
            $('#unsort').css('opacity', '0');
        }

        $('#sort').on('click', sortCars);
        $('#unsort').on('click', unsortCars);

    });
```

so my question is where is my original content in my cars variable and how to retrieve it if posible? thanks

Comment: Can you please recreate in JSFiddle or internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `sort` function sorts the array in place(meaning the original array gets changed) you need to do something differently. For example, copy the array before sorting it.
Few solutions:

```
cars.slice().sort();
```

Or

```
cars.concat().sort();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        var cars = ['Honda', 'Mazda', 'Toyota', 'Ambulance']; // store cars in my cars variable

        document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = cars; // display the cars in my html

        function sortCars() {
            var array = cars.slice();
            array.sort(); // sort 
            document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = array;
        }

        function unsortCars() {
            document.getElementById('param').innerHTML = cars; 
        }

        $('#sort').on('click', sortCars);
        $('#unsort').on('click', unsortCars);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="param"></p>
<p id="sort">sort</p>
<p id="unsort">unsort</p>
```